# Finding current mouse coordinates in a Bash shell script on macOS

Tags: bash, macos

Is there a way to find the current mouse coordinates using a Bash script on macOS? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2422652 has a solution for AppleScript.

Comment: ... Turns out I can't get that `osascript` to work on Catalina. )-: (Also, don't click the link to an external site Craig something from the Apple forum, the original site seems to be dead and the new owner just wants you to enable JavaScript so that they can display advertising.)

Comment: This is probably the same guy: https://github.com/CraigWilliams/MouseLocation

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mouse_position#AppleScript gets me syntax errors but it might just be lack of competence on my part.

Answer (score 2):

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

Output:

```
x:1345 y:493 screen:0 window:39846136
```

To install:

```
brew install xdotool
```

Comment: It doesn't work with Catalina. I tried to follow all the instructions. `% xdotool getmouselocation` 
`Error: Can't open display: (null)`

Comment: @Sunil check out https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick

```bash
❯ cliclick p
1738,220
```

To install:

```bash
brew install cliclick
```